# Celery dont send response to backend

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

In my app I use Celery and RabbitMQ.

On localhost everything works fine:

I send tasks to few workers, they calculate it and return result to **call.py** (I use [groups](http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/canvas.html#groups)).

The problem start here:

On my laptop (macbook) I have RabbitMQ, on desktop (pc, windows) - celery-workers. I start **call.py** (on laptop), it sends data to my desktop (to workers), they recieve and calculate tasks, and in the end (when all tasks succeeded) my laptop dont receive any response from workers.

No errors, nothing.

My laptop ip - 192.168.1.14. This ip I use in **broker** and **backend** parametrs, when I make Celery instanse.

In **rabbitmq-env.conf**:

```
NODE_IP_ADRESS=192.168.1.14
```

On my router I make forwading to port 5672 to 192.168.1.14.

So, if all app runs on localhost and I use my public ip (5.57.N.N.) - all works.

If I use workers on another host (192.168.1.14) I dont have response from them (calculated result).

How to fix that?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the default user guest:guest ? If so, that user can only connect via localhost. See https://www.rabbitmq.com/access-control.html#loopback-users